# How to convert a Blob type into a byte array in typescript?

Tags: typescript, angular7

I want to convert my file which extends blob to byte array ? Is there any function in typescript which can do that?

Comment: take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50859749/3617380)

Comment: side note, this is not a typescript question, it's a javascript question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fileReader

```
 var r = new FileReader();
    r.onload = function(){ alert(r.result); };
    r.readAsBinaryString(file);
```